# AVFoundation playing a sound is stopped when playing background music

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, background, avfoundation

I play a sound with AVFoundation. No problem with that. But when I play music the sound gets stopped. There is some way to play the two sounds simultaneously?
I tried with:

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];

before playing the sound without success.